# jQuery select value from dropdown dependant on text value

Tags: jquery, magento

I have magento store and a product with a dropdown with 30 options of a range of sizes. I also have a text box which I need to reference the dropdown and select a value dependant on what is written in the box.

So for example if someone types in 105 in the text box I need jQuery to automatically select the value of 100-110 in the dropdown (which in turn triggers an ajax change of price which is already in place).

Is this possible in jQuery and what functions should I be looking at?

**Edit:** jQuery code so far...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#options_483998_text").keyup(function(){
        var value = jQuery("#options_483998_text").val() * 1;
        var jQueryselect = jQuery("select#attribute592");
        var optionValue = "";
        jQuery('option', jQueryselect).each(function(){
            var range = jQuery(this).text().match(/\d+/g);
            if(range && value >= range[0] && value <= range[1]){
                optionValue = this.value;
                return false;
            }
        });

        jQueryselect.val(optionValue);jQueryselect.change();

    });
    jQuery("#options_483997_text").keyup(function(){
        var value = jQuery("#options_483997_text").val() * 1;
        var jQueryselect = jQuery("select#attribute593");
        var optionValue = "";
        jQuery('option', jQueryselect).each(function(){
            var range = jQuery(this).text().match(/\d+/g);
            if(range && value >= range[0] && value <= range[1]){
                optionValue = this.value;
                return false;
            }
        });

        jQueryselect.val(optionValue);jQueryselect.change();
    });


});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you try to explain the second paragraph with an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through each option element, and check whether the given value is within the range of the option value. **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QFfLB/2/**

```
var value = $("#inputBox").val() * 1; //Convert to number, example: 105
var elem;
$('select option').each(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();    //Example:  100-110
    var range = val.split("-"); //Example: [100,110]
    if(val >= range[0] && val <= range[1]){
        elem = this;
        return false;
    }
});
elem = $(elem); //If existent, elem will be the jQuery object,
                // representing the option element
```

This code assumes all option values to be in the following format: `x-y` (where `x` and `y` are numbers). If your code contains something like `120+`, the code has to be modified. If this is the case, post a comment with a link to your relevant code, and I will have a look at it.

**Update** - **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QFfLB/4/**
Use the `.text()` method to get the label of an option. Then, use `.match(/\d+/g)` to find the number values:

```
var value = $("#inputBox").val() * 1;    //Get number
var $select = $("select#attribute592");  //<select> element
var optionValue = "";                    //Default value
$('option', $select).each(function(){
    var range = $(this).text().match(/\d+/g); //Range
    if(range && value >= range[0] && value < range[1]){
        optionValue = this.value;
        return false;
    }
});
$select.val(optionValue);                //Set new option value
```

Comment: I've added sample of the dropdown code with specific values to my original message.

Comment: Is it possible to update the original dropdown box with the relevant selection? The reason I ask this as although we will be hiding the dropdown box the way the ajax uses the dropdown box to update the price.

Comment: Just hit a problem with this... if you select the upper value it doesn't select, so for example the range for the first option is 100-115, you can type anything from 100-114 but if you do 115 it doesn't select anything.

Comment: Say, you've got `100-110, 110-120`. Where does `110` belong? At `100-110` or `110-120`? About duplicating: Yes.

Comment: Change `>= and <` to `> and <=`. So, `range && value > range[0] && value <= range[1]`. By the way, it would then be `101-110, 111-120, 121-130, ..`

Comment: have put >= and <= to get it working the way we need to. The next issue we've seen is although it is changing the value in the dropdown it isn't actively selecting the box so that the next dropdown is activated. Have a look at http://www.justdoors.co/ultragloss-black-custom.html and you will see the script in action.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4658/discussion-between-rob-w-and-vince-pettit)

Comment: Invoke `spConfig.configureElement($('attribute592'))` on the current select box to initiate a change in the next select box (where `$` is **not** jQuery`, but Prototype.

Comment: I've updated my original post with the coding I have so far... sorry to ask again but where do I need to insert the new invoke code?

Comment: Replace `jQueryselect.change();` by `spConfig.configureElement(jQueryselect[0]);`. Solved.